# How to get spatialite_osm_net from spatialite

Tags: openstreetmap, spatialite

I am using windows 7. I downloaded spatialite-tools (precompiled) from the following site. But there is no "spatialite_osm_net" tool available. For one of my project I was trying to convert the OSM road network to spatialite road network.

http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/binaries.html

It looks like without this tool It is not possible to do it.

For your information, I tried to make this tools from the following [site](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/index) according to instruction using MinGW. But It does not work when I come to $make command. I do not know is there anything missing? or how Should I do?

```
$ cd c:/spatialite-tool-2.4.0

$ export "CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include"

$ export "LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib"

$ export "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"

$ ./configure --target=mingw32

$ make

$ make install-strip
```

So now how can I get spatialite_osm_net???

Answer (score 3):

The current version of spatialite should build OK on Windows. However you can just download the required binary from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/ and http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/ (depending on whether you want 32 bit or 64 bit binaries).

Note that it is a separate zip file.